# Is the root file different if a custom rom is installed?

Tags: rooting, root-access, recovery-mode, custom-roms, twrp

Do I need a different root file if I have installed a custom rom on Android?

Who creates root files for devices?

Comment: no (yes). no. vendor (proprietary)

Comment: @alecxs Please be descriptive for the main question. I didn't understand "No(yes)"

Comment: sorry i am lazy.. with "root file" you probably mean kernel image. usually that boot.img is the same for stock and custom rom. just some options will changed inside, for example dm-verity must be disabled. so the file is different but it's the same kernel

Comment: I mean the update.zip file :-) that they provide to enable root access. How do I change options in side? How do I disable dm-varity? Where would I find it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/systemless-root/info

Comment: Systemless root didn't answer my question completely but it did solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically root method is pretty generic. the leading tools are

- [Magisk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#downloads)
- [SuperSU](https://download.chainfire.eu/1021/SuperSU/SR3-SuperSU-v2.79-SR3-20170114223742.zip)
- phh's [SuperUser](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3216394)
- [AddonSU](https://www.xda-developers.com/lineageos-dropping-superuser-addonsu-implementation-favor-magisk-manager)

in that the order, where former one is recommended for all devices and ROMs while the last is ROM specific

However, while the rooting process is nearly the same, every device is different and there is no generic root method. First you need to unlock bootloader. Some vendors (like Huawei) decided to lock devices completely, others (like Samsung, Xiaomi, Lenovo) have there own special protections

Second, you need custom recovery (or at least, modified boot.img) which is definitely device specific and not interchangeable with other device models

Usually every device has it's own section in famous xda forum where developers share custom recovery or custom rom

Always search for root method specific for your device model

(Note: i am aware of exploit based temp root methods but decided that is out of scope and not worth a timeless answer, because development is ongoing and that exploits become outdated)

Comment: I know how to root etc. I have installed a custom rom on my device. Now I want to root too. I just want to know if the root file is different if the stock rom is not installed. Is the root file changes with rom. Thanks :)

Comment: Magisk is good. It also had the option to unroot back.

Comment: However, it has some incompatibilities with GSIs and fails to patch dm-verity with [FEC](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3817389&page=90) enabled [Strictly Enforced Verified Boot with Error Correction](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/strictly-enforced-verified-boot-with.html)

Comment: Do you know of any app that blocks internet from a specific app, not a whole system firewall or VPN that always run in the background?

Comment: [FEC](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3817389&page=45) link updated because xda doubled posts per page